# Grouping based on one column in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to group by based on Group in the below dataframe.

```
             Group
               G1
               G1
               G1
               G2
               G2
```

After Group by in the above dataframe,

```
             Group            Count
               G1                  3
               G1                  2
```

Then, I need to do a pivot table of the above dataframe based on Group.

```
                                  Count
          Group
           G1                     3
           G2                     2
```

Comment: Yes, I already tried with df.groupby('Group').count(). Its not providing me the count. It again prints out the Group values only.

Comment: use `size()`, not `count()`

Answer (score 2):

Use: `df.groupby('Group').size()`

Example:

```
In[53]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Group': ['G1', 'G1', 'G1', 'G2', 'G2']})
In[54]: df
Out[54]: 
  Group
0    G1
1    G1
2    G1
3    G2
4    G2

In[55]: df.groupby('Group').size()
Out[55]: 
Group
G1    3
G2    2
```

Answer (score 2):

depending on what you want to achieve:

```
In [27]: df.groupby('Group').size().rename('Count').reset_index()
Out[27]:
  Group  Count
0    G1      3
1    G2      2

In [28]: df.groupby('Group').size().rename('Count').to_frame()
Out[28]:
       Count
Group
G1         3
G2         2
```

Answer (score 0):

The column you groupby your dataframe becomes the index of the grouped dataframe, you need a second column to do this. You can just create one like this:

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

Just be careful, the new column is called `index`, it should be renamed.

With the new column this works just fine:

```
df.groupby('Group').count()
```

Or if you don't want `Group` to be the index of the new dataframe:

```
df.groupby('Group',as_index=False).count()
```

You can't use `as_index=False` with a one-column dataframe by the way.